# Find $(a,b),(c,d)\in G$ so $(a,b)H=(c,d)H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I had an exam today and there was the following question:

> Let $G=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ be a group and $H=2\mathbb{Z}\oplus3\mathbb{Z}$ its subgroup. Let $(a,b),(c,d)\in G$. Find a condition so $(a,b)H=(c,d)H$.

I have no idea how to approach this issue. Would like to see the proof.

Comment: What did you try? What do you know about cosets in general?

Comment: Write out what $(a,b)H$ and $(c,d)H$ mean (or what their elements are) to get a pair of equalities.

Comment: Could you be more specific? $a=c \mod 2$ and $b=d \mod 3$ suffice